# Multiple forms in in a page - load error messages via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I having multiple forms in a single page submitting via jQuery ajax. All forms use same class names.  Also i am using malsup jquery plugin for form submission.
I can successfully pass the data to a php file but the error message is reflecting on all forms div.message. I don't want to have different form ids because i need to have all ids in the jquery then.

```
<form class="myform" method="post" action="process.php">
<input type="text" value="" >
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
<div class="message"></div>
</form>

<form class="myform" method="post" action="process.php">
<input type="text" value="" >
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
<div class="message"></div>
</form>
```

jQuery part

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('.myform').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( response ){
            $.each(response, function(){
                    $('div.message').append('<div>'+message+'</span>');
                }
            }       
     });

});
});
</script>
```

How can i append the error message to the submitted form's div.message correctly?
Any help will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the msg div before post .

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.myform').on('submit', function(event) {
        msgDiv=($this).children('div.message');//before post get the msg div first
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            url: 'process.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( response ){
                $.each(response, function(){
                        msgDiv.append('<div>'+message+'</span>');
                    }
                }       
         });

    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How about if have multiple div elements for each inputs i have in for the form. For example, div.name, div.subject, etc need to assign separate variables?

Comment: no there is no need to set  separate variables if each form have just one special div like msgDiv. if each form have more than one div with the same class or same name then you should set separate variables

Comment: also another problem is i am generating the inputs dynamically from a php file, so the fields will be any number with any class name.

Comment: yes, i have more than one div elements for each input i create from the php file.

Comment: and you can add some special class name(or other variables ) in  your output code,then u just need to use the added class name (or variables )

Comment: sorry, i can't understand your last comment. Can you please show me an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63638/discussion-between-devdarsh-and-patato).