# Working with multiple ajax forms in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

After a suggestion from this question [Multiple forms in in a page - load error messages via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564413/multiple-forms-in-in-a-page-load-error-messages-via-ajax)
I am trying to work multiple forms in same page. **I am trying to append error messages in to the respective input div classes.**
I don't want to have different form ids because i need to have single id in the jquery then.
I have forms like

```
<form class="myform" name="myform">
<div class="name">
<input type="text" name="name" />
</div>
<div class="message">
<input type="text" name="message" />
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<!-- second form -->
<form class="myform" name="myform">
<div class="name">
<input type="text" name="age" />
</div>
<div class="message">
<input type="text" name="gender" />
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

and the jQuery part is

```
$('.myform').on('submit', function(event) { 
  postform = $(this); 
  event.preventDefault(); 
  $(this).ajaxSubmit({ 
   url: 'process.php', 
   type: 'post', 
   dataType: 'json', 
   success: function( response ){ 
     $.each(response, function(index, element){
       var msgdiv = postform.children('div.' + divclass).append('<span>'+message+'</span>'); 
     }
   } 
  });
});
```

however the ajax part is working but the error messages do not load in the div tags as defined in the jQuery `'div.' + divclass`. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You cannot have multiple `id`s, it's not a preference.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Changed to class but even though it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
postform.find('.message').append('<span>' + message + '</span>');
```

Comment: But you shouldn't have an #id twice in the same page. Use classes instead.

Comment: Yes, changed to classes.