# Multiple AJAX forms with the same ID on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have two AJAX newsletter subscribe forms on the same page (top and bottom). Both forms have the same ID. The top form works perfectly, however I'm unable to get the alert messages to appear in the bottom form.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27424687/working-with-multiple-ajax-forms-in-same-page) but wasn't sure how to implement the answer into my code.

Here's the form:

```
        <div class="newsletter">
            <form id="newsletter" class="newsletter-signup" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                <input id="hero-section-newsletter-email-input" type="email" name="email">
                <button class="button" type="submit">
                    Subscribe
                </button>
                <div id="newsletter-alert" style="display: none;" data-alert></div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var newsletterAlert = function(message) {
    $('#newsletter-alert').text(message);
  };

  var isValidEmail = function(email) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);
    return pattern.test(email);
  };

  $('#newsletter').on('submit', function(e) {
    var data,
        $form = $(this),
        $email = $form.find('input[type="email"]');

    e.preventDefault();
    $('#newsletter-alert').show();

    if ( !isValidEmail( $email.val() )) {
      newsletterAlert('Looks like you entered an invalid email address! Please try again.');
    } else {
      newsletterAlert('Subscribing you now...');
      data = $form.serialize();

      $.ajax({
        url: 'PATH_TO_SUBSCRIBE_PHP',
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function(msg) {
          if ( msg === 'success') {

            newsletterAlert('Success! Please check your email to confirm.');
            $email.val('');
          } else {
            newsletterAlert( msg );
          }
        },
        error: function(msg) {
          newsletterAlert('Error! ' + msg.statusText);
        }
      });
    }
  });
})();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Having any elements that have the same `id` will render the second element inert. Give your other form a different id or use `class` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the same ID for the top and bottom forms.

> An `id` must be unique in a document -- see [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id).

Instead have two separate `id`'s and reference them both in the one jQuery call when you are binding to the `submit` event:

```
$('#newsletter_top, #newsletter_bottom').on('submit', function(e) {
    // ...
});
```

and in your HTML:

```
<form id="newsletter_top" ...>
</form>

<form id="newsletter_bottom" ...>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I did that and it works fine, except if I submit the bottom form, the alert appears in both the bottom and top form. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: @user3733904 probably the same issue, you have duplicate `id`'s on the `newsletter-alert` div as well. Do the same thing by splitting `id="newsletter-alert_top"` and `id="newsletter-alert_bottom"`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have mentioned in my reply that I have already separated the ID's for the alerts. Thanks for your help